# php array_push with associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to add files to an associative array.
While searching I found the "array_push" function, but this does not work on an associative array.

Then I found that I should use this way:

```
$myArray[$key] = $value;
```

so I tried this:

```
<?php
/* some SQL code to get the user's instrument */

$dir = "./bladmuziek/$instrument";
$dh = opendir($dir);
$partijen = array();
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if (strlen($file) >= 3) {
        $file2 = str_replace (" ", "%20", $file);
        list( , $filename) = explode(';', $file);
        list($filename2, ) = explode('.', $filename);
        $partijen[$filename] = $file2;
    }
}

?>
```

The files are in this format: **69845214;Some file.pdf**
So I save the filename "**Some file**" and the href "**69845214;Some%20file.pdf**" to my array "**$partijen**".

This works fine except I have some duplicate filenames in my directory. 
(this isn't a problem in the directory because of the preceding digits)

so my array is overwriting the files with the same filename.

How can I add my information at the and of my array so all the files are kept?

Comment: Which information you wanna add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a index for generating the key of array.

```
<?php
/* some SQL code to get the user's instrument */

$dir = "./bladmuziek/$instrument";
$dh = opendir($dir);
$partijen = array();
$i = 0;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if (strlen($file) >= 3) {
        $file2 = str_replace (" ", "%20", $file);
        list( , $filename) = explode(';', $file);
        list($filename2, ) = explode('.', $filename);
        $partijen[++$i.'_'.$filename] = $file2;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes this shows all the files, but the $filename is printed on the page. So this is not the best solution for my problem. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I used your answer a bit different
`$partijen[$filename.';'.++$i] = $file2;`
This way the array sort() still works fine. I use the same explode function while displaying the files so it will not show the index number. Thanks!